# Django Class Based View - redirect if user is logged in

Tags: django

I have a login view which looks like:

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'login.html'

def post(self, request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Login failed')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'username' : username})
```

Now, I'd like to modify it so if a user is alredy logged in and visits this url, template isn't rendered and insted he is redirected to the index page (or any other than the login one). I've tried overriding get method but it didn't work. What's the proper solution then?

Comment: You are trying to redirect a logged in user to login page, is it right?

Comment: So please correct 'template isn't rendered and insted he is redirected to the login page' part.

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self, request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/yourIndex/")
   else:
         username = request.POST['username']
         password = request.POST['password']
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
         else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Login failed')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'username' : username})
```